# MysqlDump from Powershell and Windows encoding

Tags: encoding, powershell, mysql

I'm doing an export from command line on ms-dos with mysqldump:

```
& mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 -W -B dbname 
> C:\mysql_backup.sql
```

My database/tables are encoded with UTF-8 and I specify the same encoding when I did the dump. But when I open the file with Notepad++ or Scite I see an encoding of UTF-16 (UCS-2). If I don't convert the file with iconv to UTF-8 before running the import I got an error.

It seems that MS-DOS / CMD.exe is redirecting by default with UTF-16. Can I change this ?

A side note: I use Powershell to call mysqldump.

UPDATE: it seems that it occurs only when calling mysqldump from Powershell. I change the command line with the one I use in my PS script

Comment: I have never encountered this problem, and I use the same syntax. Could this be Powershell specific? Are you 100% sure it's UTF-16?

Comment: You are right I just execute the command on the same server and my file is a UTF-8 one. hum I will change the question. Thx!

Comment: Here seems to be a workaround (search for "UTF-16"): http://xahlee.org/powershell/PowerShell_for_unixer.html

Comment: Yes I just find too a workaround, call cmd directly: & cmd /c " mysqldump -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 -W -B dbname  > C:\mysql_backup.sql "

Comment: @Matthieu that works inside Powershell as well? Nice.

Comment: Wow - this is the solution.  Something about powershell (I was on server 2008, maybe an older version?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default PowerShell represents text as Unicode and when you save it to a file it saves as Unicode by default.  You can change the file save format by using the `Out-File` cmdlet instead of the `>` operator e.g.:

```
... | Out-File C:\mysql_backup.sql -Encoding UTF8
```

You may also need to give PowerShell a hint on how to interpret the UTF8 text coming from the dump utiltiy.  [This blog post](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!7212.entry) shows how to handle this scenario in the event the utility isn't outputting a proper UTF8 BOM.