# mysqldump accents

Tags: sql, mysql, dump, diacritics

in my database, the tables are **collation = latin1**

in mysqldump command i put **--default-character-set=latin1**

BUT, in sql ouput file, the accents, like **á**, appears **├í**,

**i** appears **├¡**

I don't have idea and no find solution for this :x

Comment: Don't specify any `--default-character-set` and try once. default is UTF8

Answer (score 0):

after searching lot, i found the solution in this question

[MysqlDump from Powershell and Windows encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599510/mysqldump-from-powershell-and-windows-encoding)

To resolve, insert

```
[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

in top of your PowerShell command, after, in **invoke-expression**, insert this **-Encoding UTF8**

is this the full command

```
invoke-expression $cmd | Out-File $backuppathandfile -Encoding UTF8
```